# How can i go to chatrooms?

Tags: support, reputation, chat, privileges

How can I gain reputation in order to go to chatrooms, and what is the difference between votes and reputation?

Comment: Thanks       I'm new so i 'm discovering !

Answer (score 4):

Reputation can be gained by asking or answering legitimate questions (not this: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/40193/how-can-i-travel-to-the-chatroom-just-joking )

Alternatively, you can gain +2 reputation for making constructive edits to posts.

At [20 points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), you'll be able to go to the chat room.  That's just two upvotes on answers, four on questions, or 10 good edits.

Briefly -

1. Reputation is the sum of the points you have earned for other people upvoting your contributions.  (+10 for answers, +5 for Questions, +2 for edits, -2 for each downvote). See [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) for more details.
2. Rather than trying to game the system, focus on quality content. Before posting, see if others have asked your question already. See if there are unanswered questions you can answer.
3. Understand, chat rooms are somewhat ancillary to the questions and answers and meaningful content that is being produced.

Comment: Your answer is so clear, thank u.

Comment: Cool.  If the answer is useful to you, there are two things you should do.  1 -> Upvote it.  That's what the arrows are for.  2->Click the Green checkmark. That means this "answered" your question.  You'll need to wait at least 10 minutes, but doing so will also net you an additional +2 reputation for yourself.

Comment: FInally, be sure to take the [tour](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tour)!  It's actually really good.

Comment: But be patient until i get 15 reputations